# Swagger UI's Response Body show string instead of json object after using package Swashbuckle.AspNetCodre.Annoatations

Tags: swagger-ui

The response body becomes to string as:
"{"id":"96dad743-138e-4b70-8316-5ced38ba56fe","name":"Test","hexColor":"121213","isActive":true,"planInstanceId":"a1656f48-beb5-439a-944e-24ce93679d33"}"

We want to have it show as:
{
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"name": "string",
"hexColor": "string",
"isActive": true,
"planInstanceId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}

How to set it up in c# on startUp or program.cs's Main so that it will show object instead of string, here is some setting we set:

```
builder.Services.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
                    
                });
```

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>options.EnableAnnotations();});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

Please give me hint where I should set so it will show json object not string.
Thanks

I google it and did not find correct answer. When I remove the package Swashbuckle.AspNetCodre.Annoatations from my project, then everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Naive mistakes, should be "return OK(response)" instead of "Ok(response)" in the api controller.